# Messed up layout in chrome using overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, alignment, overflow

I have a page with a list of thumbnail images. As you can see it at http://www.ariangroup.net/Album/Item/25, each image is surrounded by a frame. Every thing looks ok on FF and IE. but in chrome, when an image in that row has a height larger that 200px (Although overflow is hidden), it messes up the alignment in that row (e.g. row 2 height of first image on the left is 301px and that causes that row to not be in line).
Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `vertical-align: top;` on the class `.albumImage`. That should solve your problem!

[image]